# FDR Correction needed on a pixel-wise comparison?

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, false-positive-rate

I have a question, which twirls my mind but I can't find a robust basis to answer it!

I have a time-frequency data (let's say 5 columns x 5 rows) for each participant in two different groups. I have performed an independent t-test for each cell (I compared the value in the first column/first row between group 1 and 2 and got a p-value, then the value in the second column and first row and got a p-value, etc.). I now have a matrix of p-values (5 rows & 5 columns) to statistically map where the differences are seen. do I need to perform a multiple hypothesis testing correction? I performed multiple comparisons but only for one variable...

I'd be grateful for opinions ans answers!

Thanks in advance!